# How to run two actions at the same time cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, action

So I know CCSpawn and I have been using it to run multiple actions at the same time, but now I am encounter a problem. I made a game character that's only last for a short period of time and then disappears, and I want to use CCBlinks to notify user about it. So I want to know how I can combine CCBlinks with whatever action the character is doing? For example, character's current action state is attacking, how can I combine attacking action with CCBlinks action?

Comment: post your code that you tried --

Comment: I don't know how to do it, how can I add an action to the current action and make them both run at the same time?

Comment: if actions are different then you run new action, attacking is animation and blinks is different..you can run both with runAction twice ? try

Comment: oh man, You are a Genius, it works now, here's my code.         [hero1 runAction:[CCSpawn actions:[CCSequence actions:[CCBlink actionWithDuration:2 blinks:4],[CCBlink actionWithDuration:1 blinks:3], [CCBlink actionWithDuration:0.5 blinks:3], [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{[self removeGameObject:hero1 Team:hero1.isAlly];}], nil], nil]];